# Where to create a smiles convertor with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use this smiles conventor http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-convert-smilies-to-graphics.html to create a function that converts smiles to graphics with Laravel. So, my question is, where should I put this code? I may need to use same convertor in private messages, or somewhere else, so I don't want to do all convertion in my chat Controller, because later I may need to overwrite it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull this into a Service class.

```
namespace App\Services;

class SmileService
{
    function convertSmilies($text, $url_address_to_images_folder) // with '/' at the end
    {
        $array = array(':-)' => 'smile001.gif', // happy
        ':)' => 'smile001.gif', // happy
        ':-D' => 'smile002.gif', // very happy
        ':D' => 'smile002.gif', // very happy
        ':-O' => 'smile008.gif', // surprised / o, no
        ':-P' => 'smile007.gif', // tongue sticking out
        ':P' => 'smile007.gif', // tongue sticking out
        ';-)' => 'smile009.gif', // wink
        ';)' => 'smile009.gif', // wink
        ':-(' => 'smile003.gif', // sad
        ':(' => 'smile003.gif', // sad
        '8o|' => 'smile011.gif', // angry grin
        ':-@' => 'smile010.gif', // angry
        '8-)' => 'smile027.gif', // nerd
        ":'(" => "smile040.gif", // crying
        ':-S' => 'smile005.gif', // confused
        ':-$' => 'smile004.gif', // embarrassed
        ':-|' => 'smile012.gif', // undecided
        ':-*' => 'smile055.gif', // kissing
        ':-#' => 'smile056.gif', // don't tell anyone
        '(H)' => 'smile006.gif', // wacked out sunny face
        '<:o)' => 'smile041.gif', // party
        '(A)' => 'angel.gif', // angel
        '+o(' => 'Bo.gif', // Sick
        '(brb)' => 'smile043.gif', // be right back
        '(6)' => 'smile039.gif', // devil
        '(Y)' => 'smile049.gif', // yes
        '(N)' => 'smile050.gif', // no
        '(X)' => 'grl.gif', // girl
        '(Z)' => 'boy.gif', // boy
        '(L)' => 'smile015.gif', // love
        '(U)' => 'smile016.gif', // don't love
        '(K)' => 'smile020.gif', // kiss
        '(P)' => 'pic.gif', // picture
        '(G)' => 'gift.gif', // gift
        '(%)' => 'smile037.gif', // handcuffs
        '(F)' => 'smile019.gif', // flower
        '(W)' => 'smile018.gif', // Wilt flower
        '(D)' => 'smile036.gif', // drink
        '(B)' => 'smile035.gif', // beer
        '(C)' => 'coffee.gif', // cup
        '(^)' => 'smile054.gif', // (Birthday) cake
        '(pi)' => 'pi.gif', // pizza
        '(||)' => 'smile047.gif', // chopsticks
        '(M)' => 'm.gif', // messenger
        '(@)' => 'cat.gif', // cat
        '(sn)' => 'sn.gif', // snail
        '(bah)' => 'bah.gif', // sheep
        '(tu)' => 'smile042.gif', // turtel
        '(&)' => 'dog.gif', // dog
        ':-[' => 'smile034.gif', // Bat
        '(?)' => 'smile038.gif', // ASL - Age Sex Location
        '({)' => 'smile026.gif', // hug left
        '(})' => 'smile025.gif', // hug right
        '(pl)' => 'smile048.gif', // plate
        '(I)' => 'light.gif', // idea
        '(8)' => 'music.gif', // music
        '(ip)' => 'ip.gif', // island
        '(S)' => 'smile021.gif', // asleep / moon
        '(*)' => 'smile022.gif', // star
        '(R)' => 'smile024.gif', // rainbow
        '(#)' => 'smile023.gif', // sun
        '(li)' => 'smile052.gif', // lightning
        '(st)' => 'smile051.gif', // storm / rain
        '(um)' => 'um.gif', // umbrella
        '(co)' => 'co.gif', // computer
        '(mp)' => 'mp.gif', // mobile phone
        '(T)' => 'phone.gif', // telephone
        '(E)' => 'mail.gif', // email
        '(ap)' => 'ap.gif', // airplane
        '(au)' => 'au.gif', // car
        '(~)' => 'movie.gif', // movie
        '(O)' => 'time.gif', // time / clock
        '(so)' => 'so.gif', // soccer ball
        '(ci)' => 'ci.gif', // cigarette
        '(yn)' => 'smile046.gif', // fingers crossed
        '(h5)' => 'smile045.gif', // high five
        '(xx)' => 'smile044.gif', // x-box
        '(mo)' => 'mo.gif'); // money

        foreach($array as $s => $xc)
        {
            $text = str_replace($s, "<img align='absmiddle' src='".$url_address_to_images_folder.$xc."'>", $text);
        }

        return $text;
    }
}
```

Now in your ChatController (or any other controller)

```
use App\Services\SmileService;

class ChatController
{

    protected $smileService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->smileService = new SmileService();
    }

    public function saveMessage(Request $request)
    {
        // some code here
        $chatModel = new Chat();

        // Now convert your smilies
        $convertedMessage = $this->SmileService->convertSmilies($request->message);

        $chatModel->message = $convertedMessage;

        $chatModel->save(); 
    }

    // Could also do this when you retrieve messages 
    // from the controller instead, so that you always
    // have the same text in the DB. That way if you 
    // ever change your smile images, your data would still be intact.
}
```

All that said, this is a great opportunity for an [Angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

Comment: Thanks! but i have made a helper function and i think it works okay too!